# paracol/exam: How to continue the numbering of choices when switching between columns/rows?

Tags: lists, exam, paracol

I would like to make the choices list continue the numbering when moving from one column/row to another instead of labeling those of the first row as `A` and those of the second row as `B`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
        \begin{choices}
            \begin{paracol}{3}
            \switchcolumn[0]* \choice A
            \switchcolumn[1]  \choice B
            \switchcolumn[2]  \choice C
            \switchcolumn[0]* \choice D
            \switchcolumn[1]  \choice E
            \switchcolumn[2]  \choice F
        \end{paracol}
    \end{choices}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `choice` counter to global using `\globalcounter`. This command is defined by `paracol`, see Section 5.3 *Local and Global Counters* in the [paracol manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter{choice}
\begin{document}
    \begin{choices}
        \begin{paracol}{3}
            \switchcolumn[0]* \choice 1
            \switchcolumn[1]  \choice 2
            \switchcolumn[2]  \choice 3
            \switchcolumn[0]* \choice 4
            \switchcolumn[1]  \choice 5
            \switchcolumn[2]  \choice 6
        \end{paracol}
    \end{choices}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]